# Yii & DB2 - CLI0112E Error in assignment. SQLSTATE=22005

Tags: php, sqlite, yii, db2

I am trying to verify that submitting a form with a blank field throws a pre-defined error message saying 'field cannot be blank'. This works on a SQLite db, however on DB2 I get a db exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0112E Error in assignment. SQLSTATE=22005

The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM client WHERE id=''

client is a table that has 'id' as a pk, it is of type BIGINT, cannot be null and is auto-generated. On my page, the form has a field called 'client_id' which is where a user can specify a client to add.

My thinking is that for some reason, trying to search for '' (an empty string) in a numeric field is causing the problem. I have tried changing the data type to INTEGER but that didn't work because of various constraints. I know the error code is for 'data type mismatch', but I can't see why.

Comment: Because an empty string is an invalid integer.

Comment: That's what gets generated by Yii. I just ran the query directly and it said 'invalid character', so I removed the quotes and replaced it with NULL and it worked. Now I just need to make Yii output that, but since it's automatically generated I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Not a solution to this particular problem but we were having a similar problem elsewhere and executed direct SQL instead of using Yii's pre-made one, and we got it to work. I don't think Yii's one is bad, but with DB2 you have to get it exactly right or it throws a fit.